# codeigniter AJAX jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

my code

```
<?php foreach ($dt_pesanan_detail->result_array() as $key) {    ?>
 <select name="id_kelas" class="id_kelas">
  <?php
       echo "<option>".$key['jumlah']."</option>"
 ?>
 </select>

 <div class="siswa" id="siswa" class="siswa"></div>
<?php  ?>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(".id_kelas").change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
                    var id_kelas = {id_kelas:s};
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>transaksi/ambil_data_pelanggan_ajax",
                    data: id_kelas,
                    success: function(msg){

                        $('.siswa').html(msg);

                    }
                });
    });


        </script>
```

if result $dt_pesanan_detail more then 2 row, if I change dropdown 1 row result jquery in $('.siswa') row 1 and 2, and when i change value drop down 2 row result jquery alwas in $('.siswa') row 1 and 2.
how when i change drop down 1 row only change $("#siswa"), not to row 2..thx

Comment: Have you checked the : url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>transaksi/ambil_data_pelanggan_ajax",

Comment: $id["temp"] = $this->input->post('id_kelas');
$this->load->view('transaksidigor/siswa',$id);

Comment: I am asking that debug the url:  "<?php echo base_url(); ?>transaksi/ambil_data_pelanggan_ajax" and check what is value of this and such path exist in your site or not?

Answer (score 0):

thats because you don't have any value for select

your code should be like below one

```
 <select name="id_kelas" class="id_kelas">
     <?php foreach ($dt_pesanan_detail->result_array() as $key) { 

           echo "<option value=\"".$key['jumlah']."\">".$key['jumlah']."</option>";
     }
     ?>
 </select>
```

also make your url like this

```
        url : "<?php echo site_url('transaksi/ambil_data_pelanggan_ajax'); ?>",
```